# Chrome starts automatically when restarting my mac

Tags: macos, google-chrome, startup

I've tried to prevent Chrome from starting up when I reboot my mac.
There is no setting in the chrome settings to prevent this, It feels like Chrome is a computer virus, infecting my computer and ignoring user preferences.
I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
1) Start Chrome
2) Right-click the Chrome icon in the dock
3) Uncheck "Options > Open at Login"
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In System Preferences, go to Users and Groups

1. Make sure to unlock (if needed) by putting in your credentials
2. Click on Login Items
3. I unchecked it (then later just pressed the minus symbol and removed it entirely)
   [image]

After doing the above steps when you restart your computer, make sure you unclick "reopen windows when logging back in" as shown below. When I didn't do this step Chrome opened right back up upon restart, even though I had completely closed out of it prior to restart. you only have to do this once not every time you restart your mac.

[image]